# Selenium webdriver , testNG with java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

How to handle the Modal window?Selenium webdriver , testNG with java

For example:
Load https://business.bell.ca/shop/small-business/ 
Click on Share Via email icon below the Facebook icon on right hand side.
Modal window is displayed

How to handle this modal window as i need to take the Screen shot of that modal window?

Answer (score 1):

There isnt any modal window. If you are trying to click on **Like**, its under an iframe. To switch to it perform:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".fui-icon.fui-icon-facebook"))
        .click();
driver.switchTo().frame(
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='facebook']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Like']")).click();
```

and to switch to facebook window that follows do:

```
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

**EDIT**:
Sorry it was my mistake that i took didn't got what you tried to ask. As a workaround if you want to interact with the **modal dialog** you could use by initially waiting for the modal-dialog to appear, and since its under top-window scope only, you can interact with the fields using xpath or css, whichever you prefer. A sample code for it with xpath would be:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("shareemail")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions
    .visibilityOfElementLocated(By
        .xpath("//*[@id='emaillightboxmodaljs']")));
driver.findElement(
    By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-id-3']/div/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/input"))
        .sendKeys("acd");
```

Comment: I have asked the query regarding the ICON handling below the Facebook Icon.

I am unable to take the Screen shot of that modal window which is displaying after i click on the message icon.


please be clear how to have a control on that modal window.

Comment: My mistake. Updated the answer accordingly. Thanks. and for taking screenshot you can use getScreenshotAs method declared in TakesScreenshot interface.